# checking rows of row_number result on condition of another column

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that outputs some rows that I need to "filter".

The data I want to filter is like this:

```
rownum value
1       0
2       0
3       1
4       1
```

I need the first 2 rows, but only when they have "0" in the value-column.

The structure of the query is like this:

```
select count(x)    
from     
(     
    select row_number() over (partition by X order by y) as rownum, bla, bla    
    from [bla bla]
```

group by [bla bla]
    ) as temp
    where

```
/* now this is where i want the magic to happen */

temp.rownum = 1 AND temp.value = 0

AND

temp.rownum = 2 AND temp.value = 0
```

So I want x only when row 1 and 2 have "0" in the value-column.

If either rownumber 1 or 2 have a "1" in the value-column, I dont want them.

I basically wrote the where-clause the way I wrote it here, but it's returning data sets that have "1" as value in either row 1 or 2.

How to fix this?

Comment: @tim i have an "order by" in the over-clause, forgot it in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A value in a single row for a given column can never be both `1` and `2` at the same time.

So, first of all, either use `OR` (which is what I believe you intended):

```
WHERE (temp.rownum = 1 AND temp.value = 0)
OR (temp.rownum = 2 AND temp.value = 0)
```

Or simplify the query altogether:

```
WHERE temp.rownum <= 2 AND temp.value = 0
```

---

From here, you will get just the first two rows, and only if `value = 0`. If you only want rows when *both* rows are returned (i.e. both rows have `value = 0`), add

```
HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
```

to the query.

Comment: so having 2 seperate "checks" on rownum by "temp.rownum =" doesnt work? do i have to check it in one single statement?

Comment: @msa Not the way you have it because you're saying `rownum` must equal both 1 and 2 at the same time...

Comment: but if i use "or", cant it then be that rownum 1 has a value of 1 while rownum 2 has a value of 0 or vice versa? /edit: i would like to upvote you, but not enough reputation... :<

Comment: @msa Ok I think I get you now, you want to return rows only when both rows have a value of 0.

Comment: exactly. i now wrote it like you did simplifying the query (with temp.rownum <= 2) - it still results some datasets that have a "1" as value on rownum 2.

Comment: @msa I added a bit to the bottom of my answer

Comment: ok, i only checked on the dataset that i would falsely return, and it doesnt return it anymore. seems to work, i'll check on the whole DB. you mind explaining what exactly this does? what is "1" in "count(1)"?

Comment: @msa The 1 in count(1) just counts the number of rows without trying to select a column (and have to worry about inadvertently not counting nulls). The `HAVING` clause returns rows where a certain condition is true, and you can use aggregates here. `HAVING COUNT(1) = 2` basically says to return rows only where there are exactly two rows to be returned.

Comment: sorry for disturbing, but while we're at it: how can i additionally check of these are really the ONLY rows with value = 0? right now, when i check the first 2 rows, it also returns datasets that have value=0 on rownum 3, rownum 4 and so on. it would be nice if i could say: i need value = 0 on row 3 and lower, but row 4 has to have value = 1.

Comment: @msa That's a bit of a different scenario and a completely different query really. Can I suggest you ask a new question, and include sample data and output?

Comment: really? would it be that different? no subquery-possibility or something? but now that i think of it, that would make check rownum on different values again, i think... hm. because when i check for the first 2 rows on value=0, i dont want datasets that have value=0 on row 3 or further. i might ask a new question, thank you very very much for your help!